# How do I send a notification to Slack from AWS CloudWatch on a specific error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, amazon-cloudwatch, slack, amazon-sns

I'm trying to setup notifications to be sent from our AWS Lambda instance to a Slack channel. I'm following along in this guide:

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/generate-slack-notifications-for-aws-cloudwatch-alarms-e46b68540133

I get stuck on step 4 however because the type of alarm I want to setup does not involve thresholds or anomalies. It involves a specific error in our code. We want to be notified when users encounter errors when attempting to login in or sign up. We have try/catch blocks in our Node.js backend to log errors to CloudWatch at various points in the login/signup flow where we think the errors are most likely happening. We would like to identify when those SPECIFIC errors are occurring and send a notification to a Slack channel built for this purpose.

So in step 4 of the article, what would I have to do to set this up? Or is the approach in this article simply the wrong one for my purposes?

Thanks.

Comment: Your alarm does involve a threshold: greater than 1 occurrence of some string in your Cloudwatch logs.

Comment: Thanks hephalump, your comment plus Marcin's is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step 4 titled "Create a CloudWatch Alarm" uses `CPUUtlization` metric to trigger an alarm.

In your case, since you want to use CloudWatch Logs, you would create [CloudWatch Metric Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) based on the logs entries of interest. This would produce custom metrics based on your error string. Subsequently, you would create `CloudWatch Alarm` of this metric as shown in the linked tutorial for `CPUUtlization`.

Comment: That's great, Marcin! That article addresses exactly what I need. Thanks!